# EagleCad stopped working after update to 13.10

Tags: upgrade, 13.10

If I try to execute the program from terminal I get this error:

```
/home/rick/eagle-6.4.0/bin/eagle: error while loading shared libraries:
libXcursor.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The program worked fine in 13.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libXcursor library is missing. This should solve your problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libxcursor1
```

Also, it looks like you are no using Ubuntu packaged version of EagleCAD. You could just install that version by running `sudo apt-get install eagle`, and forget about the trouble with custom installer from EagleCAD homepage.

Comment: I have tried that,rick@Rick951:~$ sudo apt-get install libxcursor1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libxcursor1 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded I think I need a i386 lib.

Comment: Why are you not using Ubuntu packaged version of EagleCAD? You could just install that version by running `sudo apt-get install eagle`, and forget about the trouble with custom installer from EagleCAD homepage.

Comment: There is not a package for 13.10, I checked that before.  I also have paid for the licensed version that worked fine until I upgraded.  Eagle 6.4 installed with no problem with the Eagle download.   I did a ldd from the bin directory.  All libs are from the i386 directory that it needs.   the i386 libxcursor must have been removed when I upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10

Comment: Andrejs, The software Center does not have a package for 13.10, but wen I did sudo apt-get install eagle, it also installed an i386 version of Libxcursor,  All is well now!  Thanks!

Comment: Andrejs, Sorry, I am new to this, how do I except you answer and give you credit?

Comment: Just mark the answer as accepted, more info is here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work Thanks!